# How to zoom certain subview on UIScrollVIew pages?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I intend to create a photo viewer.I have a scrollView which have 3 pages. The second page contains an ImageView . I want to return the imageView as the zoomable view.
But every time I start to zoom, it automatically scroll to the first page while the imageView did zoomed ( not on screen, can not scroll). I don’t know what is wrong.

I write some code in the delegate method :`-(void)didzoom`and method like `[scrollview setContentOffset]`.
 I am very confused now.
[image]

Comment: You should put that image view in its own zoomable scroll view inside the parent scroll view.

Comment: @BrianNickel you are right.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ZoomScale to you ScroolView then set delegate.

```
scrollview.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
scrollview.delegate = self;

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return imageView;
}
```